# Errors While Installing Bumblebee

Tags: ubuntu, driver, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04

Yesterday I installed Bumblebee-nvidia, But I am getting few warnings Like shown below :

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be 
opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf: No such file or directory
```

Should I have to worry about these warnings ? If yes then how to fix it?

Comment: This is probably better suited for askubuntu.com

Comment: ok, Thank you !

Comment: Same problem here too